# Docker + Kubernetes build

Tags: docker, deployment, containers, kubernetes, docker-registry

I am trying to use Docker + Kubernetes for my application management.

I have installed kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet (got the steps from google docs) for Kubernetes cluster.

Now cluster is having 2 node(1 Master, 1 Child)

I have a customize Dockerfile , how can it use it as a Kubernetes pods ?

If this is not possible,
How to transmit the docker build to the Kubernetes child from master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a private Docker registriy outside or inside the cluster or work with local (pre-pulled) images.

1. Outside the cluster you might want to look at these:

   - [Docker registry image](https://docs.docker.com/registry/)
   - [Jfrog Artifactory registry](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories)
   - [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss)
   - [Dockerhub private registry](https://hub.docker.com/)
   - [Google private registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/)
   - [Amazon ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)
   - [Quai.io registry](https://quay.io/)
   - [Azure registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/)
2. Inside the cluster you might want to look at the [Private Docker Registry in Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/registry)
3. If you're not interested to use a registry, you could also build the image on every Kubernetes node so that Docker doesn't have to pull it. To avoid that Kubernetes tried to pull anyways you would then have to set the `imagePullPolicy` of your containers to `Never`. That's described within the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images).

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfiles create images which are used by pods, Kubernetes only uses your created docker image it doesn't build docker images for you. I think what you want to do is:

- create an image from your dockerfile by using `docker build`
- send that image to dockerhub using `docker push`
- create a kubernetes deployment that uses your image https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/

That should get you in the right direction but you will have to read up more :)

Comment: That is the problem for me. I cannot upload my image into the DockerHub. Is there any other way apart from that ?

Comment: Are you using minikube on your own local machine? You are not able to upload or you are not allowed to for whatever you are working on? Google has its own private image server and you can also run your own, but if you are using minikube on your own machine the solution is easy.

Comment: @feelbot Thanks for the reply. I am not using minikube, I am using kubeadm which is on alpha release as of today.